# awk: if line startswith do something, else print

Tags: awk

Suppose the content of a file `test.txt` is:

```
>this_should_be_changed
blabla
>this_should_be_changed
foofoo
>this_should_be_changed
barbar
```

I am trying to get this output:

```
>this_changed
blabla
>this_changed
foofoo
>this_changed
barbar
```

I would like to use `awk` for this. I have tried:

```
awk -F "_" '/>/ {print $1"_"$4}' test.txt
```

which outputs:

```
>this_changed
>this_changed
>this_changed
```

How can I tell `awk` that it should also print lines that do not match the search pattern `>`?

**Edit**

Based on the accepted answer, I found the solution:

```
awk -F "_" '/>/{print $1"_"$4; next}1' test.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution with substitution in case you want to use current line later in your code.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  match($0,/_.*_/)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

---

---

With your shown samples only, please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^>/{sub(/_.*_/,"_")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{              ##Checking condition if line starts with > then do following.
  sub(/_.*_/,"_")  ##Substituting everything from _ to till _ with _ here.
}
1                  ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** With OP's code fix it would be `awk -F "_" '/>/ {print $1"_"$4;next} 1' Input_file`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, I need to access the fields. The real world example is more complicated. Sorry, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: @MKR, could you please do let me know more clearly what didn't work here? Since I can't see your actual samples, please do add more information on same.

Comment: @MKR, Ok, could you please do try my 1st solution(EDIT one) now and let me know then? That uses regex and don't perform substitution so later onwards you can use line too, let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingth13. The solution was the use of `next` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `sed` one liner:

```sh
sed '/^>/s/_.*_/_/' test.txt

>this_changed
blabla
>this_changed
foofoo
>this_changed
barbar
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '/this_should_be_changed/{sub(/should_be_/,"")}1' file
```

Output:

```
>this_changed
blabla
>this_changed
foofoo
>this_changed
barbar
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/this_should_be_changed/ {   # identify the record to change
    sub(/should_be_/,"")     # sub() changes the record
}1' file                     # output changed and unchanged records
```